# find possible combination of amounts in range

Tags: php, math, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for an algorithm example in PHP to take a set of different sized items (numbers) and print each possible combination that can fit in a specific larger number, excluding those that don't fit.

Preferably the algorithm example would be able to adjust as the specific large number shrinks.

For example 
Input:

```
$timeleft = 160;
$times = array("wash dishes"=>"25", "vacuum"=>"45", "Laundry"=>"120");
//Output after processing:
Echo $combo1;
"Laundry, wash dishes"
Echo $combo2;
"Wash dishes, vacuum"
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: please provide examples of sample input and expected output, so you get an answer

Comment: When you say "combination" do you mean it the same way it is defined in mathematics where the order is irrelevant, or does it include permutations where the items can happen in different orders? Is each item only to be performed once?

Comment: Order is irrelevant and each item can only occur once in a combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is similar to the 0-1 Knapsack Problem.

Here is the solution in PHP:

```
#########################################################
# 0-1 Knapsack Problem Solve with memoization optimize and index returns
# $w = weight of item
# $v = value of item
# $i = index
# $aW = Available Weight
# $m = Memo items array
# PHP Translation from Python, Memoization,
# and index return functionality added by Brian Berneker
#
#########################################################

function knapSolveFast2($w, $v, $i, $aW, &$m) {
 
    global $numcalls;
    $numcalls ++;
    // echo "Called with i=$i, aW=$aW<br>";
 
    // Return memo if we have one
    if (isset($m[$i][$aW])) {
        return array( $m[$i][$aW], $m['picked'][$i][$aW] );
    } else {
 
        // At end of decision branch
        if ($i == 0) {
            if ($w[$i] <= $aW) { // Will this item fit?
                $m[$i][$aW] = $v[$i]; // Memo this item
                $m['picked'][$i][$aW] = array($i); // and the picked item
                return array($v[$i],array($i)); // Return the value of this item and add it to the picked list
 
            } else {
                // Won't fit
                $m[$i][$aW] = 0; // Memo zero
                $m['picked'][$i][$aW] = array(); // and a blank array entry...
                return array(0,array()); // Return nothing
            }
        }   
 
        // Not at end of decision branch..
        // Get the result of the next branch (without this one)
        list ($without_i, $without_PI) = knapSolveFast2($w, $v, $i-1, $aW, $m);
 
        if ($w[$i] > $aW) { // Does it return too many?
 
            $m[$i][$aW] = $without_i; // Memo without including this one
            $m['picked'][$i][$aW] = $without_PI; // and a blank array entry...
            return array($without_i, $without_PI); // and return it
 
        } else {
 
            // Get the result of the next branch (WITH this one picked, so available weight is reduced)
            list ($with_i,$with_PI) = knapSolveFast2($w, $v, ($i-1), ($aW - $w[$i]), $m);
            $with_i += $v[$i]; // ..and add the value of this one..
 
            // Get the greater of WITH or WITHOUT
            if ($with_i > $without_i) {
                $res = $with_i;
                $picked = $with_PI;
                array_push($picked,$i);
            } else {
                $res = $without_i;
                $picked = $without_PI;
            }
 
            $m[$i][$aW] = $res; // Store it in the memo
            $m['picked'][$i][$aW] = $picked; // and store the picked item
            return array ($res,$picked); // and then return it
        }   
    }
}
 
 
 
$items4 = array("map","compass","water","sandwich","glucose","tin","banana","apple","cheese","beer","suntan cream","camera","t-shirt","trousers","umbrella","waterproof trousers","waterproof overclothes","note-case","sunglasses","towel","socks","book");
$w4 = array(9,13,153,50,15,68,27,39,23,52,11,32,24,48,73,42,43,22,7,18,4,30);
$v4 = array(150,35,200,160,60,45,60,40,30,10,70,30,15,10,40,70,75,80,20,12,50,10);
 
## Initialize
$numcalls = 0; $m = array(); $pickedItems = array();
 
## Solve
list ($m4,$pickedItems) = knapSolveFast2($w4, $v4, sizeof($v4) -1, 400, $m);
 
# Display Result 
echo "<b>Items:</b><br>".join(", ",$items4)."<br>";
echo "<b>Max Value Found:</b><br>$m4 (in $numcalls calls)<br>";
echo "<b>Array Indices:</b><br>".join(",",$pickedItems)."<br>";
 
 
echo "<b>Chosen Items:</b><br>";
echo "<table border cellspacing=0>";
echo "<tr><td>Item</td><td>Value</td><td>Weight</td></tr>";
$totalVal = $totalWt = 0;
foreach($pickedItems as $key) {
    $totalVal += $v4[$key];
    $totalWt += $w4[$key];
    echo "<tr><td>".$items4[$key]."</td><td>".$v4[$key]."</td><td>".$w4[$key]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td align=right><b>Totals</b></td><td>$totalVal</td><td>$totalWt</td></tr>";
echo "</table><hr>"
```

;